# Map, reduce, filter apply to for loops and while loops

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and learning use of Map, reduce, filter.
It is becoming very hard for me to comprehend how it can replace for and while loops.
For ex for below code, I would like to replace for loop

```
function addMultiplesOf3And5(N::Int)
  sumOfMultiples = 0
  if(N == 3)
    return sumOfMultiples + N
  end
  for i = 3:N-1
    if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
      continue
    elseif(i % 3 == 0)
      sumOfMultiples += i
    elseif(i % 5 == 0)
      sumOfMultiples += i
    end
  end

  return sumOfMultiples
end
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Update :
This is what I did after going through tutorials

```
function addMultiplesOf3And5(N::Int)
  array = range(1,N-1)
  return reduce(+, map(x -> multiples_of_3_Or_5(x), array))
end

function multiples_of_3_Or_5(n)
  if(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)
    return 0
  elseif(n % 3 == 0)
    return n
  elseif(n % 5 == 0)
    return n
  else
    return 0
  end
end
```

Final:

```
function addMultiplesOf3And5(N::Int)
  array = range(1,N-1)
  return reduce(+, filter(x -> ((x%3==0)$(x%5==0)), array))
end
```

Comment: Perhaps give some details on what you've tried so far.  See also [StackOverflow Homework Guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Been a while since I used a map function, but from what I recall, it applies a function to each element of a list.. So of course a for loop can also do that.  So it should be clear how a for loop can be used instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand how you can replace your 'for loop + if block' code with 'map / reduce / filter' you need to know exactly how they work and why they might be chosen instead.

---

## 1. The `map` function

`map` is a function that takes a *function* variable and a list as arguments, and returns a *new* list, where each element is the result of applying the function to each element of the old list. So for example if your variable `f` refers to a function `f(x) = x + 5` you defined earlier, and you have a list `L=[1,2,3,4,5]`, then `map(f, L)` will return `[f(L[1]), f(L[2]), f(L[3]), f(L[4]), f(L[5])]`

So if you have code like:

```
f(x) = x + 5;
L = [1,2,3,4,5];
A = zeros(5);
for i in L
  A[i] = f(i);
end
```

You could rewrite this as a mapping operation like so:

```
A = map(x -> x + 5, [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

## 2. The `reduce` function

`reduce` takes a *binary* function variable (i.e. a function that takes two arguments) and a list as arguments. What it does is probably best explained by an example. Calling reduce with the `+` operator, and list `[1,2,3,4,5]` will do the following:

```
Step 1:   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  %           : 5 elements
Step 2:   [1+2, 3, 4, 5]   % [3,3,4,5] : 4 elements
Step 3:   [3+3, 4, 5]      % [6, 4, 5] : 3 elements 
Step 4:   [6+4, 5]         % [10, 5]   : 2 elements
Step 5:   [10+5]           % [15]      : 1 elements
result: 15
```

i.e. we have reduced the list to a single result by successively applying the binary function to the first pair of elements, consuming the list little by little.

So if you have code like:

```
f(x,y) = x + y
L = [1,2,3,4,5];
A = L[1];
for i in 2:length(L)
  A = f(A, L[i])
end
```

you could rewrite this as a reduce operation like so:

```
A = reduce(x,y -> x+y, [1,2,3,4,5])
```

## 3. The `filter` function

`filter` takes a *predicate* function (e.g. `iseven`, `isnull`, `==`, or anything that takes an argument and performs a test on it, resulting in true or false) and a list, tests each element of the list with the function and returns a new list that only contains the elements that pass that test. e.g.

```
filter(iseven, [1,2,3,4,5])   # returns [2,4]
```

## The answer to your problem

If I understand correctly, `addMultiplesOf3And5` takes a number N (e.g. 20), and does the following:

- *filter* out all the elements that can be divided by either 3 or 5 from the list [1,2,3,...,20]
- successively add all elements of the resulting list together using a *reduce* function.

You should be able to use the above to figure out the exact code :)

Comment: _go_ julia!  my new go-to language for exploratory data analysis

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the function in the question is supposed to calculate, but:

```
addMult3or5(N) = N==3 ? 3 : sum(filter(x->((x%3==0)$(x%5==0)),3:N-1))
```

calculates the same thing.

`sum` is a a `reduce`-like function for the `+` operation.

Hope this helps clarify.

Also, `$` is the exclusive-or operation in Julia.

Comment: You can replace the `sum(x)` with `reduce(+, x)`, if that would make it clearer as to how it relates. (BTW I would guess this is of a FizzBuzz varient))

Comment: Is it possible to _chain_ the functions  instead of nesting them - e.g. `collection.filter(predicate).map(predicate).sum`  ?

Comment: @javadba The piping operator `|>` allows some chaining in this case i.e. `filter(x->((x%3==0)⊻(x%5==0)),3:N-1) |> sum`. Also note the xor operator changed form `$` to `⊻`

Comment: A more piped version could be: `addMult3or5(N) = N==3 ? 3 : 3:N-1 |> v->filter(x->((x%3==0)⊻(x%5==0)),v) |> sum`